# Dynamically change specific item in nested lists of unknown depth in Python

Tags: python, list, nested

I am looking for a nicer solution for changing a specific item in a nested list of unknown and varying depth.

Say, I have a list `lst = ['a', 'b', [['c'], ['d', ['e', 'f']]]` and I want to change the `'e'` to an `'x'`.
I could do this by simply hard coding:

```
lst[2][1][1][0] = 'x'
```

But I'd have to use an unknown number of indices to change different items. Changing the `'c'`, e.g., would only require 3 indices.

To make it a bit more dynamic I've already written a function that returns the wanted indices of a certain item, in this case `indices = get_indices('e', lst)` would return the list `[2, 1, 1, 0]`

So my current solution is the following function:

```
def set_element(lst, index, value):
    levels = len(index)
    if levels == 1:
        lst[index[0]] = value
    elif levels == 2:
        lst[index[0]][index[1]] = value
    elif levels == 3:
        lst[index[0]][index[1]][index[2]] = value
    elif levels == 4:
        lst[index[0]][index[1]][index[2]][index[3]] = value
    elif levels == 5:
        lst[index[0]][index[1]][index[2]][index[3]][index[4]] = value
    elif levels == 6:
        lst[index[0]][index[1]][index[2]][index[3]][index[4]][index[5]] = value
    else:
        return False
    return True
```

Calling `set_element(lst, indices, 'x')` would do the trick.

But ... frankly ... I'm not quite happy with this solution, there has to be a smoother, pythonic way to achieve this. I'm probably missing something.

Can anybody think of an even more dynamic way where I don't have to predefine the maximum number of possible levels?

**EDIT:**

In the above example I've got the indices from the list I'd like to alter, which makes the method seem a bit overly complicated. In my specific case, however, I actually need to use the indices of an item to change another item in a different list of the very same structure.

So I have to insist on using the list of indices.

Comment: There is and it utilizes `recursion`. Googling it will get you far since your case is a very typical one.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', [['c'], ['d', ['e', 'f']]]]

def change(seq, what, make):
  for i, item in enumerate(seq):
    if item == what:
      seq[i] = make
    elif type(item) == list:
      change(item, what, make)
  return lst

print(change(lst, 'c', 'k'))
#['a', 'b', [['k'], ['d', ['e', 'f']]]]
```

It's a bit specific for your case, but it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, I forgot to mention, that using the indices is quite crucial, so that you can change an item at the exact position of an item in a different list of the same structure. But apart from that it's definitely an very good solution.

Answer (score 3):

Lists only accept integer indices. You can subclass `list` to overload the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` to accept tuples and lists as indices. By overloadeding `__init__`, we can simplify variable creation.

```
class nestedlist(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) == 1:
            super().__init__(nestedlist(arg) if type(arg) is list else arg for arg in args[0])
        else:
            super().__init__(nestedlist(arg) if type(arg) is list else arg for arg in args)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if type(key) is int:
            return super().__getitem__(key)
        if len(key) == 1:
            return super().__getitem__(key[0])
        return self.__getitem__(key[0])[key[1:]]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if type(key) is int:
            super().__setitem__(key, value)
            return
        if len(key) == 1:
            super().__setitem__(key[0], value)
            return
        self.__getitem__(key[0]).__setitem__(key[1:], value)

lst = nestedlist(['a', 'b', [['c'], ['d', ['e', 'f']]]])

lst[2,1,1,0] = 'x'
# or
indices = [2,1,1,0]
lst[indices] = 'x'
```

Answer (score 2):

I **really** believe that your function `get_indices` is already almost the answer to your problem - just when you find the element - change it! =)

but as an answer - use recursion (as you probably used in find_indices)

```
def set_element(lst, index, value):
    if(len(index)==1):
        lst[index[0]] = value
    else:
        set_element(lst[index[0]],index[1:],value)
```

Comment: That's true, I could have changed it when i found it. But, I'm afraid I forgot to mention, that using the indices of a specific item is crucial. Because then I can change an item at the same position in another list of the very same structure, which comes in quite handy... So your answer is excellent, thanks.